# Splitting single row into more columns based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've a requirement to get 3 similar set of row data replacing the column value if any certain value exists in the given column('[#]' in this case). For example

```
---------------------
Type     Value
---------------------
1        Apple[#]
2        Orange
3        Peach[#]
```

I need to modify the query to get value as below

```
 ----------------------
  Type        Value
 --------------------
   1         Apple1
   1         Apple2
   1         Apple3
   2         Orange
   3         Peach1
   3         Peach2
   3         Peach3
```

I could not come up with logic how to get this

Comment: How do you know you want 3 apples and 3 peaches, but only 1 orange?

Comment: It is based on the '#' sign that exists in the column. I forgot to mentioned that

Comment: so if there is [#] then you always want 3, otherwise 1?

Comment: if there is [#], I want 3 rows of similar columns appending values from 1 to 3 dynamically using a select statement. if [#] does not exists I want to be able to get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the same result without recursivity :

```
select Type, Value from MyTable where Right(Value, 3) <> '[#]'
union
select Type, Replace(Value, '[#]', '1') from MyTable where Right(Value, 3) = '[#]'
union
select Type, Replace(Value, '[#]', '2') from MyTable where Right(Value, 3) = '[#]'
union
select Type, Replace(Value, '[#]', '3') from MyTable where Right(Value, 3) = '[#]'

order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. This is a very simple and easy to understand solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one digit (as in your example), then I would go for:

```
with cte as (
      select (case when value like '%\[%%' then left(right(value, 2), 1) + 0
                   else 1
              end) as cnt, 1 as n,
             left(value, charindex('[', value + '[')) as base, type
      from t
      union all
      select cnt, n + 1, base, type
      from cte
      where n + 1 <= cnt
     )
select type,
       (case when cnt = 1 then base else concat(base, n) end) as value
from cte;
```

Of course, the CTE can be easily extended to any number of digits:

```
(case when value like '%\[%%'
      then stuff(left(value, charindex(']')), 1, charindex(value, '['), '') + 0
      else 1
 end)
```

And once you have the number, you can use another source of numbers.  But the recursive CTE seems like the simplest solution for the particular problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE 
(
    Type int,
    Value varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES (1, 'Apple[#]'), (2, 'Orange'), (3, 'Peach[#]')

SELECT sd.Type, cr.Value
FROM @SampleData sd
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (IIF(Charindex('[#]', sd.Value) > 0, 3, 1)) 
            x.[Value] + Cast(v.t as nvarchar(5)) as Value
    FROM 
        (SELECT Replace(sd.Value, '[#]', '') AS Value) x
        Cross JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) v(t)
    Order by v.t asc

) cr
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/RJZUY24026)

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive CTE

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    Type int,
    Value varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(1, 'Apple[#]'),
(2, 'Orange'),
(3, 'Peach[#]');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Type,
        IIF(RIGHT(Value, 3) = '[#]', LEFT(Value, LEN(Value) - 3), Value) AS 'Value',
        IIF(RIGHT(Value, 3) = '[#]', 1, NULL) AS 'Counter'
    FROM
        #test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        B.Type,
        LEFT(B.Value, LEN(B.Value) - 3) AS 'Value',
        Counter + 1
    FROM
        #test AS B
        JOIN CTE
            ON B.Type = CTE.Type
    WHERE
        RIGHT(B.Value, 3) = '[#]'
        AND Counter < 3
)

SELECT 
    Type,
    CONCAT(Value, Counter) AS 'Value'
FROM 
    CTE
ORDER BY
    Type,
    Value

DROP TABLE #test
```